# Is there a maximum size that web pages should be kept under?

Tags: performance, page-size

[Posted this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430374/is-there-a-maximum-size-that-web-pages-should-be-kept-under) before Ben Voigt was nice enough to direct me here.  Anywho, here is my question:

When I say size I'm talking about bytes not pixels.

I'm curious if there is any consensus on what the maximum size should be for various categories. Specifically:

```
Broadband connections
Dialup connections
Mobile connections
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first question is how long is too long for the user to wait. Let's use 1.5 seconds, because that's what Google judges as too slow (see [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15786/google-webmaster-tools-site-performance-says-site-is-faster-but-shows-it-slow-in)). So assuming a dialup user gets the maximum 56kbits/second, that's 5.6 kbytes (roughly) so that's 8.4kb. That's pretty small.

Broadband speeds vary, but assuming 1Mb for the sake of argument, that's 150k (1Mbit/second remember).

Mobile varies again. 2G (GPRS) is the same as dialup. EDGE is 236.8 kbit/s so thats 35k. 
3G UMTS is 384 kbit/s, so 57k.

Comment: Good answer, but are you confusing bits with bytes? 1 bit = 0.125 bytes, so 56 kilobits per second for 1.5 seconds = 84 kilobits (kb) = 84000 bits = 10500 bytes = **10.5kilobytes.** (kB) (See [this calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=56kbps+for+1.5+seconds) on Wolfram Alpha.)

Comment: 1.5 seconds may be what google targets for its search results but other services it provides such as gmail and docs don't get anywhere near that number unless your on a very fast connection. I think the time people will wait depends on what they are waiting for.

Comment: @Nick Network speed is in bits and page size is in bytes and I was careful to keep the two separate. There are 8 bits in a byte, but when it comes to serial transmission there may be 1, 1.5 or 2 stop bits and an optional parity bit, so it's easier to just assume 10 bits to the byte for rough calculation.