# What is the ideal file size for a web page?

Tags: html, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a maximum size that web pages should be kept under?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16299/is-there-a-maximum-size-that-web-pages-should-be-kept-under)

What is the ideal file size for a web page?

Specifically when it comes to image sizes, what's the total file size for a webpage which includes several images.

I tend to compress images down as much as possible before it starts to visually lose quality.

We run several CMS website's and the clients tend to ask this question a lot! I'd love to hear another view on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by compressing your images down as much as possible you are doing everything correctly. As for what is a good size....every website will be different. Also things like compressing your CSS and JS should help.

Some useful articles about making your site more streamlined:

- http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/decrease-webpage-load-times/
- http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/site-speed-performance/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html